# JS - Check For http:// In TextField Input

Tags: javascript, regex, url, uitextfield, titanium

I am writing my app in JavaScript using Appcelerator's Titanium IDE. I've been working on this and trying out Regex for about two hours now. Anyway, My question is this:

I have a URL bar. If the user starts the input with 'www.' I want it to add the 'http://' in front of it, and if they start with 'http://', it would not add it. And, if there is no 'www.' either, it would add the full 'http://www.'.

A practical way of going about this would be something like maybe using Regex (I've never used it before, don't have any experience) or something to see if the first two letters are 'ht' or 'ww', and if that isn't a match then it would just add the 'http://www.'

What I just posted above is what I would think one would do, and I'm most likely sounding entirely mad because it makes no sense. I'm not really asking for the whole code to be written out; I can add the various things, I'm just looking for maybe some code/input that would be useful for me being able to plugin and use/modify.

Thanks!

EDIT: Great responses! I'm sure most-if not all work, so I did my best and upvoted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another solution:

```
var appendHttpToUrl = function(url){
    var httpwww = "http://www.";
    var rx = /(^http:\/\/|^www\.)/g;
    if(url.indexOf(httpwww) === -1){
      if(url.indexOf("http://") > -1 || url.indexOf("www.") > -1){
        url = url.replace(rx,httpwww);
      }else{
        url = httpwww+url;
      }
    }
    return url;
}
```

Here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/TJn7A/5/.

Comment: Works perfect in every case but one, I think I'm grasping it so I'm trying to fix it, but the case is when you have the full http:// and the www., it appends another www. Anyway, you get the answer because this is nice and simple!

Comment: Tried to fix it, still doesn't work. If you get a chance, it'd be great if you could amend it to include the full http:// and www. together. Otherwise, I'm sure I'll get it eventually. Thanks!

Comment: I fixed it and updated the demo.  The key was wrapping all of the logic in a check to see if the url is good as is.

Answer (score 3):

Regex is too complicated for this string manipulation. Try this instead:

```
<input onchange="testUrl(this)">

<script>
function testUrl(el){
    if(el.value.indexOf('http://') == 0){
        if(!el.value.indexOf('http://www.')){
            el.value = 'http://' + el.value.substr(6);
        }
     } else {
        el.value = 'http://www.' + el.value.substr(6);
     }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I see this is web based. I'm going to try and implement this, and I'll get back to you

Comment: why would regexp be too complicated?

Comment: @lawlOr Look at the answer above mine that isn't even doing the string replacement. This kind of problem doesn't need more than a few moments thought. Anytime I do a regex it takes time to design and test. This is probably a reflection of my lack of regex proficiency - which I think is a common deficiency.

Comment: @OrbitingEden hrm, not trying to offend anyone, but i used a regex, my solution is a 2-liner an in my opinion it's just as clear as substringing :) (I'm really just asking out of curiosity, maybe you're seeing something i don't...)

Comment: @lawlOr I am acknowledging my own limitations and inferring that most developers share my lack of proficiency with regex. I use regex where needed. Using it unnecessarily makes the code Augean to grok.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(url.match(/^http:\/\/$/)
  // do stuff for when they start with http://

if(url.match(/^www\./))
  // do stuff for when they start with www

if(!url.match(/(www?\.?|htt?p?:?\/?\/?)/))
  // do stuff for a matching ww or ht...
```

Breaking it down...

- `^` is the start of the pattern
- `$` is the end of a pattern
- `(...|...)` is either the left or the right part
- `\/` and `\.` is escaping where necessary the special characters with `\`
- `?` is making the previous character optional

Comment: Question, is `match` a Regex expression?

Comment: yes I mean as you say, and I am aware that the OP specifies that nothing is to be done at that point

Comment: `.match()` is a method that operates on strings, so... `var x = "my string"; alert(x.match(/^my/));` will alert a truthy value because the string stored in x matches the regex defined between the `/`es in the `match` method.

Comment: Gotcha, I'll try your solution now!

Answer (score 0):

I just hacked this. Yes it's ugly but it also handles https :)

```
function fixURL(input){
    var r = input.match(/^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(.*)$/);
    return ((r[1] ? r[1] : 'http://') + (r[2]?r[2]:'')  + r[3]);
}
var input="example.com/test";
alert(fixURL(input));
```

if you find a case where this function fails. please fix it ;-)